# Array in Java, how to populate

Tags: java

Hi i'd like to populate array in Java. I'm trying to do it on easily way

```
int[] tab = null;

for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
 {
tab[i]=i;
}
```

Why this constructions not working ? 
error: null pointer exception

Comment: You need to create your array (allocate memory for the integers you want to store) : `int[] tab = new int[5];`. You should read this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Ok, but if i need to create array dynamically?

Comment: Then use a class that implements the `List` interface. ArrayList is one of the implementation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: after you create foo: `tab = new int[foo];`

Comment: When you say dynamically do you mean the array resizes, or you don't know the size of the array until the program is actually running (so size not known at compile time)

Comment: You get NullPointerExpetion because you did not allocate memory for the integers

Comment: ArrayList<Integer> sounds like what you need. Note that you can't store primitives like `int` in `List`s, so you need to wrap them in `Integer` objects (autoboxing will help you here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic allocation means you should be using one of the Collection instances, such as a List.  If you have some constraint (such as homework rules) that says you must use an array, then you have to do the following:

- declare and instantiate the array to some arbitrary size: `int[] intArray = new int[20];`
- during the addition of the elements, check if the index is equal to the length - 1:  `if(index == length - 1)` , and if true,

  - create a temporary array of a size that is some multiple of the original array's size (usually 2x) `int[] temp = new int[intArray.length*2];`
  - copy the elements from the original array to the temp array
  - reassign the temp variable value to the original: `intArray = temp;`
  - after the loop, create a new array that is the correct length and copy all values from the original to the new one.  (this is because the size will most certainly be wrong -- the length will be more than the number of elements).

In pseudo code, it looks like this:

```
int[] intArray = new int[20];
int index = 0;
loop:
   if(index >= intArray.length - 1){
        int[] temp = new int[intArray.length * 2];
        copyAll: intArray->temp // use System.arrayCopy
        intArray = temp;
   }
   intArray[index] = value;
   index++;
endloop:
// resize because intArray will likely be too big
int[] temp = new int[index];
copyAll intArray -> temp;
intArray = temp;
```

As you can see, it's much, much nicer to use the Collection framework:

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
loop:
   intList.add(value);
endloop
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how you implement it

```
 int[] tab = new int[5];

 for(int i=0; i<tab.length; i++)
 {
   tab[i]=i;
 }
```

Comment: As the OP has mentioned "dynamically" creating the array, by which I assume they mean size not know at compile time i'd add that you can use a variable to set the array size, so int[] tab = new int[i]; where i is an integer

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your array before you use it:

```
int[] tab = new int`[5];
```

If you need something that is dynamicaly allocated use something like Vector or ArrayList:

For example:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

     int elements_to_add = 5;
     for(int i=0; i<elements_to_add; i++)
     {
       list.add(new Integer(i) );
     }
```

Comment: it is recommended to use `ArrayList` instead of `Vector`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would implement this array in the simplest way possible:

```
int[] tab = new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Your code doesn't work because you never create a new object to hold the elements of the array, it just creates space for a reference to that object.  Before you can reference the object using

```
tab[i]
```

you must create a new object like this:

```
tab = new int[5];
```

So, if you really want to implement this variable in a for loop for whatever reason, here's how you should do it:

```
final int ARRAY_SIZE = 5;
int[] tab = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];

for(int i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++){
    tab[i] = i;
}
```

Now, if you want to increase the number of elements in your array, you just need to change the ARRAY_SIZE variable.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that you **declare** this array and pass it null, you don't create any object here. You have only a reference to null. That's the reason of your error. What you have to do is initialize this array like   `int []myArray = new int[5];`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work :

```
int[] tab = new int[5];

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    tab[i] = i;
}
```